# Call by pointer become call by reference to pointer

Tags: c++, sdl, overloading, sdl-2

I have a couple of errors, where I think I'm calling a function and supplying some variables by pointer and some by value. However, I'm getting compiler errors because, somehow the call by pointer variables are changed to reference to pointer.

Here is the error

```
g++ -Wall -c -std=c++11  -I.   -c -o SDL_Lesson2.o SDL_Lesson2.cpp
SDL_Lesson2.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
SDL_Lesson2.cpp:56:42: error: call of overloaded ‘renderTexture(SDL_Texture*&,     
SDL_Renderer*&, int, int)’ is ambiguous
SDL_Lesson2.cpp:56:42: note: candidates are:
In file included from SDL_Lesson2.cpp:8:0:
sdlWrapper.hpp:40:6: note: void renderTexture(SDL_Texture*, SDL_Renderer*, int, int)
sdlWrapper.hpp:54:6: note: void renderTexture(SDL_Texture*, SDL_Renderer*, int, int,    
SDL_Rect*)
SDL_Lesson2.cpp:57:43: error: call of overloaded ‘renderTexture(SDL_Texture*&,    
SDL_Renderer*&, int&, int)’ is ambiguous
SDL_Lesson2.cpp:57:43: note: candidates are:
In file included from SDL_Lesson2.cpp:8:0:
sdlWrapper.hpp:40:6: note: void renderTexture(SDL_Texture*, SDL_Renderer*, int, int)
sdlWrapper.hpp:54:6: note: void renderTexture(SDL_Texture*, SDL_Renderer*, int, int,    
SDL_Rect*)
```

The code that is at these lines is:

```
SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, 
    SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
SDL_Texture* background = loadTexture("./background.bmp", renderer);
SDL_Texture* image = loadTexture("./image.bmp", renderer);
...
int bW, bH;
SDL_QueryTexture(background, NULL, NULL, &bW, &bH);
renderTexture(background, renderer, 0, 0);
renderTexture(background, renderer, bW, 0);
```

So, I'm wondering, why is the call ambiguous. In my mind, `renderTexture(background, renderer, 0, 0)` is clearly `renderTexture(SDL_Texture*, SDL_Renderer*, int, int)`. I'm wrong, but I can't figure out why.

Also, between the two lines the first `int` changes from calling by value to call by reference. That is also a mystery to me.

I believe the problem comes from two overloaded versions.

```
void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, int x, int y, int w, int h);
```

and

```
void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, SDL_Rect dst,
SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr);
```

These versions, don't look the same to me. But because SDL_Rect is just four ints in a struct I can see how they might be confused for each other by the compiler.

Should I just remoce one of these functions? Or does the problem lie elsewhere, and I'd just be hiding the problem by removing one of the functions?

Comment: Try compiling with `clang++`. It takes the same arguments as `g++`, but its error messages are often __much__ more useful.

Comment: Not sure the protopypes you've shown are correct. Judging by the prototypes shown in the error messages... and guessing from yours I'd say the problem lies on renderTexture with default parameter that when the default parameter is not specified is being confused with the other version.

Comment: I'd also recommend working with the bare `C` library instead of using an `C++` wrapper. You can use `std::unique_ptr` with custom `Deleter`s to 'objectify' the `C` pointers.

Comment: jsantander, I wish you had put your as an answer, cause it was just me being dumb with having default parameters.

void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, int x, int y);
  
    void renderTexture(SDL_Texture *tex, SDL_Renderer *ren, int x, int y,
 SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr);

Comment: @CallMeNorm ... well it was not a full answer since I wasn't sure what I was answering to...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to the second question, the second call registers as an int& because it has the option of fulfilling that signature.  Literals can only be passed by value, whereas variables can be passed by reference or value.  Thus `0` can only match signatures which take `int` whereas `bW` can match signatures which take `int` or `int&`.

Regarding the first question, are you sure you've copied those two lines exactly out of sdlWrapper.hpp?  It doesn't look like the candidate signatures match the ones you've provided.